# How to perform paypal embedded payment on webpage

Tags: javascript, paypal, lightbox, payment

I managed to implement paypal's embedded payment feature on my site. However, instead of producing a lightbox effect while remain on the same page, the javascript cause a creation of a new window to load on clicking payment button and form a payment page like this:

[image]

I also got my info from this site [here](https://www.x.com/people/Praveen/blog/2010/11/01/switching-over-to-embedded-payments) which apparently works for most people in their browsers. any idea how this lightbox thing is suppose to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Apparently, what i did not do was to position the html codings according to this method by the reference site from paypal:

```
 <form action="ap_api_caller.php" method="post"> <!-- all your other html form elements go here-->
 <input id="pay_button" src="btn_checkout_paypal.png" type="image">
 <input type="hidden" name="expType" value="light"/>
 </form>
```

I had all the table, tr,td and other html tags surrounding these essential inputs within the form and that apparently block the light-box from occurring. So i had to cut the hidden input line of code which matter in terms of triggering the paypal UI and place it just before i close my form tag.

Lesson learnt is that element placement can prevent scripts from functioning.

Comment: According to Paypal's site, they seem to open a popup window unless the user has selected to "remember me" in which case they can display a lightbox.  Is that the experience you've had?

Comment: Simon, this is the experience I have.  Lightbox works if the user has selected "Remember me" otherwise a new window opens.  The payment confirmation or cancellation also appears in this popup window which is rather annoying.  Need to dig into the javascript archives to work out how to close this window and direct the response to the parent window.